# Always answer Yes to replace package Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, yaourt

I am trying to build the latest KDE Frameworks git packages. However, I currently have installed the stable non-git packages. In order to install all of the git packages I need to answer 'y' to all of the replace prompts one by one. I usually use --noconfirm to skip prompts, but when it asks to replace a package, it defaults to 'no'. I want it to default to 'yes' in this case.

Comment: I think this question was marked as a dup by mistake. It doesn't ask how to "assume yes to every question" which is the dup here, but specifically how to answer yes to "replace" question. Assuming "yes" to every question is dangerous, while assuming "yes" to "replace" questions is not. E.g. I'm personally tired that every time I update system, some packages were moved elsewhere, and I have to answer "yes" to dozens of questions. Just assume "yes", I don't care! But I can't assume "yes" to every question in general, it's dangerous.

Comment: OP is already using the `--noconfirm` option, so I'd say they are trying to assume yes for every question in general and it just happens to not work for the replacement question (among others). I don't see any reason to reopen it.

Answer (score 5):

See `man yes`.

Try if `yes| your-pacman-command` will do.

Comment: But this would answer "yes" to all questions, not to "replace" one.